# Contradiction convergence in probability and convergence almost surely

Tags: probability

I am trying to understand intuitively why almost sure convergence is different (read stronger) than convergence in probability. I came up with a wrong 'counter-example', but I don't understand why it is wrong:

Convergence in probability means that $X_n  \overset{p}\to X \iff P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\to0$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

Suppose that $X_n  \overset{a.s}{\not \to}X$.
Thus there exist some set $A$ with positive measure s.t $\lim_{n\to \infty}|X_n-X|\not= 0 $ on the set $A$ (with $P(A)>0$) $\iff$ there is an $\epsilon^*$ such that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $m\geq n$ with $|X_m-X|>\epsilon^*$ on $A$.

But then, take $\delta<P(A)$. We have for $\delta, \epsilon^*$ that there does not exist $N$ such that  $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon^*)<\delta$ for all $n\geq N$ because for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $m\geq n$ with $|X_m-X|>\epsilon^*$ on $A$ and $P(A)>\delta$, implying $X_n  \overset{p}{\not\to} X$.

Conclusion: $X_n \overset{p} \to X$ implies $X_n \overset{a.s}{\to}X$ which is obviously not correct.

I hope understanding why this is not a correct counter-example helps my understanding of the difference between convergence in probability and almost sure convergence.

Comment: I lose you at para 4, "But then...".  You seem to argue that if $X_n$ does not converge a.s. that then it does not converge i.p.  (1) How does this contradict $X_n$ converges a.s. implies it converges i.p.,  (2) Your argument seems to also imply convergence i.p. implies convergence a.s.. Which we know is false, because there are examples where i.p. convergence holds and a.s. convergence does not.  My suggestion: rewrite para 4 more carefully, making the argument clearer, avoiding use of numbers like .001.

Comment: @kimchilover I hope the last paragraph is more clear now. Where do I go wrong?

Comment: In the third paragraph, what guarantees that the same $\epsilon^*$ works for every $\omega \in A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the misunderstanding may arise in your third paragraph. The biconditional claim you make isn't true. What is true is

> $X_n \overset{a.s}{\not \to} X$ a.s. iff there exists a set $A$ with $P(A)>0$ such that for all $\omega \in A$ there exists $\epsilon(\omega)$ such that $|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| > \epsilon(\omega)$ for infinitely many $n$.

You seem to confuse the order of the quantifiers on the right-hand side of the iff. That is, "for all $\omega \in A$ there exists $\epsilon(\omega)$..." is not logically equivalent to "there exists $\epsilon$ such that for all $\omega \in A$..."

Comment: I see, and there is no way to guarantee that $\inf \epsilon(\omega)>0$ which implies that the argument as above can not be made?